# JMSTemplate receive() : Return Immediately if empty

Tags: java, jms

I am using the JMSTemplate.receive(String destName) method to receive messages from the Queue. 
The issue that I am facing is that the method will wait infinitely when the queue is empty. 
For this I added a timeout parameter, but this timeout will add delay which is not preferable.

Q1. What can I do for receive to return immediately if the queue is empty.

Q2. Suppose if I add a timeout value of 1ms, will this cause a problem if my message is large and if fetch time goes beyond 1ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A1. Use the JMS API call [`receiveNoWait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html#receiveNoWait--).

A2. From my understanding of the JMS specification, the timeout is for the client to *begin* receiving a message. It's not for the total time required for `receive()` to return. Therefore, I wouldn't expect you to have a problem with a 1ms timeout and receiving a "large" message. That said, JMS implementations may differ here so it's worth testing just to be sure.

Comment: Since I am Using the JMSTemplate, it does not have a receiveNoWait() method. Thats available only on the consumer API. But checked on the JMSTemplate, there is a static field RECEIVE_TIMEOUT_NO_WAIT which can be used. Trying with 1ms Timeout as well